# android View class android:focusedByDefault xml tag

Tags: android, view

I saw in google's android documnetation that View has  android:focusedByDefault xml tag but when in android studio typing the same it is showing that there is no such tag. Why so? Has it been removed? I am using android studio 2.2.3

Answer (score 1):

On the contrary, this attribute will only become available in Android O :)

Note the "Android O Developer preview" mark instead of "added in API level X" in the [documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#setFocusedByDefault(boolean))

To get a taste of what's coming you can [download pre-release SDKs](https://developer.android.com/preview/index.html) and a system image, but it is not yet certain if this solution will be backported to the support library, so even after release it will take a while to be adopted.

Otherwise I would recommend learning about all the workarounds people have been using for the last couple of years, for instance the `<requestFocus/>` tag.